# SwiftUI: Large grid view - performance vs. layout issues

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to build a large spreadsheet type view with SwiftUI that needs to be able to handle 5000 rows and 200 columns.

With this amount of data it seems to be necessary to use lazy loading in both axes. With the following code performance is great, but it seems due to the lazy loading in the `LazyHStack` there are layout issues when scrolling fast vertically and horizontally at the same time (see video below). When changing the `LazyHStack` to a regular `HStack` the layout issues are gone, but performance is unbearable. Is there any way to have both?

```
ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal], showsIndicators: true) {
    LazyVStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
         ForEach((1...5000), id: \.self){ item in
              LazyHStack (spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach((1...200), id: \.self){ cell in
                          Text("Cell")
                             .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                             .border(Color.green)
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}
.frame(width: 800, height: 600)
```

[image]

Btw. I have also tried using LazyVGrid which also has performance issues with a large amount of columns.

Comment: Try to use `LazyVStack`+`HStack`

Comment: That's what I have tried as well, but performance is bad with `HStack` because there are so many columns.

Comment: I had no luck in implementing large collections using SwiftUI components (LazyVGrid, Grid, etc...). None of them keep up with UICollectionView. So I ended up using UICollectionView and using UIHostingConfiguration in the cells...

Comment: so nothing that works with macOS :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UICollectionView` wrapped in `UIViewRepresentable`. Performance-wise it works much better than `LazyVGrid`, but I'm not entirely sure how it will behave with this kind of layout.

[Here's](https://www.averyvine.com/blog/programming/2019/06/07/uicollectionview-and-uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource-in-swiftui) an example of implementation.

Let me know, if you find a better solution!